# How do I best put a processing limit on Duktape's engine?

Tags: duktape

I realize the use of `DUK_USE_EXEC_TIMEOUT_CHECK` is experimental (as of 1.5) but I'm unclear how to best utilize it.  What I'm trying to do is put a hard limit on opcode execution to prevent bad scripts from killing my process via infinite loops, large processing blocks, etc.  I've defined what I think is appropriate, namely:

```
#define DUK_OPT_INTERRUPT_COUNTER
#define DUK_OPT_EXEC_TIMEOUT_CHECK duk_my_exec_timeout

int duk_my_exec_timeout( void *udata ) {
    return stop_processing ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Issue: I have lots of contexts, but `udata` isn't sufficient to differentiate them as near as I can tell.  This might not be necessary for my needs, though.

Problem: The function gets called in unexpected places, like during `duk_create_heap` and even simple `duk_peval_string` calls, with no way for me to know why.

I've hacked together what I think gets me by for now by modifying the `duk__executor_interrupt` code to pass in the thread/context `interrupt_init` member like so:

```
if (DUK_USE_EXEC_TIMEOUT_CHECK(thr->interrupt_init, thr->heap->heap_udata)) {
    ...
}
```

and it seems that when it's non-zero, I've hit some internal opcode processing limit.  Does this sound right?

My timeout routine then looks like:

```
int duk_my_exec_timeout( int interrupt, void *udata ) {
    if ( interrupt ) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The interrupt check macro is intended to be called "occasionally" by the engine so there isn't a fixed place where you should expect it to be called. A typical solution is to record a start timestamp when starting an operation and check current time against the start time in the macro (in practice, a function called by the macro). When the difference is large enough, a timeout can be indicated which causes a RangeError to propagate out of the engine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So, a few problems with that mostly 1) the udata parameter doesn't distinguish contexts (that I'm aware), so I can't associate a certain "start timestamp" on a context with a particular context during the callback, and to a lesser extent 2) clock time really isn't a good measure for me, since other system delays and other tasks and even clock resolution don't give me a good view into execution load of a script... really for me opcodes of execution is a better measure.  I get that it would be difficult to include native code in that measure but that's less of a concern.

Comment: Unless you're using duk_suspend() and duk_resume() (which were not yet part of Duktape 1.5.1) you should only be calling into one Duktape context at one specific point in time, so it should be possible to arrange a timeout for that without a ctx reference. But you're right that more flexibility would be nice.